# MapKit & Google Maps

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios7.1

Recently included maps using apple's MapKit. I understand MapKit uses Google Maps. I would however like to know if the app developer is charged for using Google maps.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's MapKit only used Google Maps up to iOS 5.1 as stated in the ["Important" note in the `MKMapView` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html):

> **Important**: In iOS 5.1 and earlier, the Map Kit framework uses the Google Mobile Maps (GMM) service to provide map data.

Since then, and including iOS 7.1, MapKit uses Apple's mapping service instead.

However, regardless of iOS version, the developer is not charged for using maps.

Comment: Thank you for that Anna my own app is an IOS 7.1 application and I am using MapKiT

Answer (score 0):

Developers are not charged for using google maps.